# What depends on glibc.i686 -- yum

Tags: yum, dependencies, glibc

yum is skipping certain packages because of glibc.i686. What I want to know is what is using glibc.i686 ( which I guess is the source of the failure ) ?

```
sudo yum -y update --skip-broken
[sudo] password for xxxxx: 
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Adding en_US to language list
Found 2 installed debuginfo package(s)
Enabling fedora-debuginfo: Fedora 14 - x86_64 - Debug
Enabling rpmfusion-nonfree-debuginfo: RPM Fusion for Fedora 14 - Nonfree - Debug
Enabling rpmfusion-free-updates-testing-debuginfo: RPM Fusion for Fedora 14 - Free - Test Updates Debug
Enabling updates-testing-debuginfo: Fedora 14 - x86_64 - Test Updates Debug
Enabling livna-debuginfo: rpm.livna.org for 14 - x86_64 - Debug
Enabling rpmfusion-free-updates-debuginfo: RPM Fusion for Fedora 14 - Free - Updates Debug
Enabling rpmfusion-nonfree-updates-debuginfo: RPM Fusion for Fedora 14 - Nonfree - Updates Debug
Enabling rpmfusion-free-debuginfo: RPM Fusion for Fedora 14 - Free - Debug
Enabling updates-debuginfo: Fedora 14 - x86_64 - Updates - Debug
Setting up Update Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
--> Processing Dependency: glibc(x86-64) = 2.12.90 for package: gdb-heap-0.5-2.fc14.x86_64
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.13-1 set to be updated
---> Package glibc.x86_64 0:2.13-1 set to be updated
---> Package glibc-common.x86_64 0:2.13-1 set to be updated
---> Package glibc-devel.x86_64 0:2.13-1 set to be updated
---> Package glibc-headers.x86_64 0:2.13-1 set to be updated
---> Package nscd.x86_64 0:2.13-1 set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
--> Running transaction check
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.12.90-21 for package: glibc-2.12.90-21.i686
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.12.90-21 for package: glibc-2.12.90-21.x86_64
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.13-1 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: glibc = 2.13-1 for package: glibc-common-2.13-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: glibc = 2.13-1 for package: glibc-headers-2.13-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: glibc = 2.13-1 for package: nscd-2.13-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: glibc = 2.13-1 for package: glibc-devel-2.13-1.x86_64
---> Package glibc.x86_64 0:2.13-1 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: glibc = 2.13-1 for package: glibc-common-2.13-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: glibc = 2.13-1 for package: glibc-headers-2.13-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: glibc = 2.13-1 for package: nscd-2.13-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: glibc = 2.13-1 for package: glibc-devel-2.13-1.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    glibc-2.13-1.i686 from updates
    glibc-2.13-1.x86_64 from updates
    glibc-common-2.13-1.x86_64 from updates
    glibc-devel-2.13-1.x86_64 from updates
    glibc-headers-2.13-1.x86_64 from updates
    nscd-2.13-1.x86_64 from updates
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it shows right in the top, the package that depends on a specific version of another package is `gdb-heap-0.5-2.fc14.x86_64`. Either remove it or find a replacement that depends on the newer version of glibc.